# weblogic jndi node not deleting post removal of web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, apache-camel, weblogic, jndi

I have an camel application deployed in weblogic server. The camel engine is started from servlet and the processors bind to the camel registry using below piece of code.
registry = context.getRegistry(); //here registry is instance of Registry.
JndiRegistry jndiRegistry = (JndiRegistry) registry.getRegistry();
jndiRegistry.bind("referenceJNDINodeName", new UserReferenceObject()); //UseReferenceObject is simple POJO class with a method having required implamentation.

When application is deployed in weblogic, you can view the **JNDI node** with name "referenceJNDINodeName" in **Weblogic** **JNDI tree**.

When you remove the application from the application, i think, ideally it should remove the corresponding **JNDI node** aswell from **JNDI tree**. 
But, the **JNDI node** "referenceJNDINodeName" still appears in **JNDI tree** post web application removal aswell.

Due to this, when you try to redeploy the application, getting JNDI name conflict and application is not deploying.

How to remove the **JNDI node** name on undeploying the application from weblogic server.

Answer (score 0):

The following should probably work if you want to unbind it when undeploying it. I'm using InitialContext since JndiRegistry does not have unbind.

```
@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    try {
        unbind("referenceJNDINodeName");
        camelContext.stop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Couldn't destroy context as wanted", e);
    }
}

private void unbind(String name) {
    try{
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        initialContext.unbind(name);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        LOG.error("Couldn't unbind '{}'", name);
    }
}
```

But you could also check if it exists in the initialcontext, and if it does, rebind it? Or do not bind it.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me an idea. I think, we can unbind using below piece of code. I will verify the below code and confirm you.                         JndiRegistry jndiRegistry = (JndiRegistry) registry.getRegistry();
  jndiRegistry.getContext().unbind("referenceJNDINodeName"); // getContext will return teh InitialContext as you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Answer i got is below:

JndiRegistry jndiRegistry = (JndiRegistry) registry.getRegistry(); jndiRegistry.getContext().unbind("referenceJNDINodeName"); // getContext will return teh InitialContext

This worked.